# Saving Image from Mobile client on the Server?

Tags: c#, sql, http, ios5

I have a quick question regarding saving the images uploaded from the mobile application on the server!!
I am uploading the images from the mobile application to the wcf web service so the flow is something like that
 I convert the NSImage to base64 String and HTTP POst it to the service, What should be the best way to store the image on the server.
**1) Should I store the base64 string in the SQL Server database and retriever it whenever the image is required and send it to the mobile where it will be reversed to NSImage?
2) Convert the base64 to Image and store it in the local directory on the server?
3) Store the string in the text file?**

Answer (score 0):

The best answer, I'm Afraid, is "It Depends".

How will the images, once on the server, be accessed *most often*?  Will it be server-side or mobile-side?  Will you have to send these images to other people who don't have your system?

If the bulk of the access is **server-side**, I would recommend storing the raw string in SQL server, then having some separate process (could be trigger or timer based) that converts them into the image files and saves them locally.  Then it is an easy matter for your server-side code to link to the images.  You can have a bit flag in the table that you set to true when the raw data has been converted to an image.

If the bulk of the access is going to be other **mobile clients**, and you already have a good means for transmitting the base64 string, I'd leave in their raw form for ease of transmitting back to mobile.

You could even combine these two approaches for the best of both worlds.  Keep the string-format for sending back to other mobile clients but use the image for server-side display.

I'd stay away from the text files!

Hope that helps.